# Callback pattern for handling socket response

Tags: go, socket, callback

I am in the process of learning go and am coming from a PHP, JS, and Nodejs background.

I created a package that is a client which connects to a socket server and processes the data received from the server.  I am using a callback pattern and am wondering if this is frowned upon in the Go community.  Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
// SocketClient allows handles the socket connection to a server
type SocketClient struct {
    Host string
    Path string
    conn *websocket.Conn
}

// SocketResponse function callback for data from socket
type SocketResponse func(res []byte, err error)

// Connect create the connection with the host
func (sc SocketClient) Connect(cb SocketResponse) {
    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, os.Interrupt)

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "wss", Host: sc.Host, Path: sc.Path}

    var err error
    sc.conn, _, err = websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        cb(nil, err)
    }

    defer sc.conn.Close()

    done := make(chan struct{})

    // anonymous function call
    go func() {
        defer sc.conn.Close()
        defer close(done)
        for {
            _, message, err := sc.conn.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                cb(nil, err)
            }
            cb(message, nil)
        }
    }()

    // ...
}
```

And then in another file I actually initialize SocketClient and call Connect...

```
sc.Connect(func(res []byte, err error) {
    // handle the response
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using a callback pattern and am wondering if this is frowned upon in the Go community.

"callback pattern" shouldn't be frowned upon (they are used in "first-class functions" for instance: https://blog.golang.org/first-class-functions-in-go-and-new-go https://dave.cheney.net/2016/11/13/do-not-fear-first-class-functions)

However regarding your code, I don't think that it looks like idiomatic go code.

---

*[Don't just check errors, handle them gracefully](https://go-proverbs.github.io/)*

```
sc.conn, _, err = websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)

if err != nil {
    cb(nil, err)
}
```

You pass the `err` to your callback, but you then continue inside the `Connect` function: if you couldn't dial, why do you continue?

---

*[Never start a goroutine without knowing how it will stop](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/12/22/never-start-a-goroutine-without-knowing-how-it-will-stop)*

```
go func() {
    defer sc.conn.Close()
    defer close(done)
    for {
        _, message, err := sc.conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            cb(nil, err)
        }
        cb(message, nil)
    }
}()
```

The inner `for` loop will never stop (so will your goroutine).

---

One possibility would be to change it like this:

```
// SocketResponse function callback for data from socket
type SocketResponse func(res []byte)

// Connect create the connection with the host
func (sc SocketClient) Connect(cb SocketResponse) error {
    u := url.URL{Scheme: "wss", Host: sc.Host, Path: sc.Path}

    var err error
    sc.conn, _, err = websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer sc.conn.Close()
    for {
        _, message, err := sc.conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        cb(message)
    }
}
```

Some properties of this code :

- on dial error, it stops
- it reads all the messages until one error is encountered
- it blocks (but `go sc.Connect()` is easy to write)

Some possible evolutions:

- to continue even in case of errors, you could return a channel of errors (and send all errors encountered)
- also use a channel to report the received messages
- to control when the `Connect` method should stop, you could use a `context` or **split your method in 3 parts: `Connect`, `ReadMessage` & `Close`**

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the information about the callback as well as the detailed review in general! Are you recommending to use a channel rather than a callback? If I were to send the error in the callback and then return to stop the function could I then just implement a reconnect function that has a backoff procedure and have the code that started the listening to call reconnect?  Also don't I need to block on connect before listening?

Comment: `Are you recommending to use a channel rather than a callback?` both options are valid and kind of interchangeable (the provided callback can send the values into a channel / the goroutine receiving the values may call a callback). The drawback of the channel is the buffer size management (either the channel is given as argument, or the size of it), but its closing mechanism is a nice way to indicate the end of the messages (whereas a callback would need some additional logic).

Comment: `If I were to send the error...` it actually depends on the error: if it is an error meaning that no more `Read` may succeed (connexion closed for instance) in this case a new connection is needed. But if it is an error just for decoding this message (formatting or transmission error), subsequent `Read` should succeed. What can be done when (connect, listen, reconnect...) depends mainly on the library!